# Using a join statement to link data together from 2 different datatables into one in C#

Tags: c#, join, datatable

I am trying to get some data from one datatable (facilData) and data from another datatable (ownerData) and write it to another datatable (dataStore). The second is not identical to the first. When I attempted my code below, I get the following error: ***"Unable to case object of type System.DBnull to System.String"***. Then the debugger takes me back and highlights **(int)table2["rowIndex"]** in the code below.

```
public void Write2Sheet(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2, DataTable dt3, String newFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            //Merge the three Datatables into the single Datatable source
            var mdata = from table1 in facilData.AsEnumerable()
                        join table2 in ownerData.AsEnumerable() on (int)table1["rowIndex"] equals (int)table2["rowIndex"]
                        select new
                        {
                            rowIndex = (int)table1["rowIndex"],
                            Prog = (string)table1["Prog"],
                            cStatus = (string)table1["cStatus"],
                            bStatus = (string)table1["bStatus"],
                            fID = (string)table1["fID"],
                            fNam = (string)table1["fNam"],
                            fAdd = (string)table1["fAdd"],
                            fCity = (string)table1["fCity"],
                            fState = (string)table1["fState"],
                            fCode = (string)table1["fCode"],
                            oInfo = (string)table2["oInfo"],
                            pgRecId = (string)table1["pgRecId"],
                            lAct = (string)table1["lAct"]
                        };

            foreach (var rec in mdata)
            {
                var row = dataStore.NewRow();
                row["rowIndex"] = rec.rowIndex;
                row["Prog"] = rec.Prog;
                row["cStatus"] = rec.cStatus;
                row["bStatus"] = rec.bStatus;
                row["fID"] = rec.fID;
                row["fNam"] = rec.fNam;
                row["fAdd"] = rec.fAdd;
                row["fCity"] = rec.fCity;
                row["fState"] = rec.fState;
                row["fCode"] = rec.fCode;
                row["oInfo"] = rec.oInfo;
                row["pgRecId"] = rec.pgRecId;
                row["lAct"] = rec.lAct;


                dataStore.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Write2LogFile("The data tables couldn't merge because: " + e.Message);
        }

        //Write from the Datatable source to the new spreadsheet and save it
        try
        {
            FileInfo newSheet = new FileInfo(fileName);
            using (ExcelPackage xPkg = new ExcelPackage(newSheet))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xPkg.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                var cell = worksheet.Cells;
                int rI = 2;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dataStore.Rows)
                {
                    string iDX = rI.ToString();

                    worksheet.Cells["A" + iDX].Value = dr["Prog"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["B" + iDX].Value = dr["cStatus"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["C" + iDX].Value = dr["bStatus"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["D" + iDX].Value = dr["fID"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["E" + iDX].Value = dr["fNam"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["F" + iDX].Value = dr["fAdd"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["G" + iDX].Value = dr["fCity"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["H" + iDX].Value = dr["fState"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["I" + iDX].Value = dr["fCode"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["J" + iDX].Value = dr["oInfo"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["K" + iDX].Value = dr["pgRecId"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["L" + iDX].Value = dr["lAct"].ToString();

                    rI++;
                }

                xPkg.Save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Write2LogFile("Data was not written to spreadsheet because: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, if it tries to cast to DBNull, have you tried to use **(int?)** instead of **(int)** ? Shouldn't work...
Where are table1 and table2 defined? (facilData, ownerData)

Comment: Have you checked that your rowIndex all have values in both facilData and ownerData ?

Comment: If value is null or empty then pass DBNull.value

Comment: One of the value is null and you are trying to convert into string that's why issue is there, debug the solution you will get the error at that point handle null value

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out. Instead of trying to do the query syntax, I went with the method syntax. I added an additional class as a container for my objects I wanted to add to the single datatable. Although none of the row-indices were null, I added a null check anyway. Here is my updated code:

```
public void Write2Sheet(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2, DataTable dt3, String newFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            //Merge the three Datatables into the single Datatable source  

            //method syntax
            var mdata = facilData.AsEnumerable().Where(f => f[0] != typeof(DBNull)).Join(ownerData.AsEnumerable(),
                        table1 => table1.Field<int>(0),
                        table2 => table2.Field<int>(0),
                        (table1, table2) => new Class1   //container class
                        {
                            rowIndex = (int)table1[0],
                            Prog = table1[1].ToString(),
                            cStatus = table1[2].ToString(),
                            bStatus = table1[3].ToString(),
                            fID = table1[4].ToString(),
                            fNam = table1[5].ToString(),
                            fAdd = table1[6].ToString(),
                            fCity = table1[7].ToString(),
                            fState = table1[8].ToString(),
                            fCode = table1[9].ToString(),
                            oInfo = table2[1].ToString(),
                            pgRecId = table1[10].ToString(),
                            lAct = table1[11].ToString()
                        });

            foreach (var rec in mdata)
            {
                var row = dataStore.NewRow();
                row["rowIndex"] = rec.rowIndex;
                row["Prog"] = rec.Prog;
                row["cStatus"] = rec.cStatus;
                row["bStatus"] = rec.bStatus;
                row["fID"] = rec.fID;
                row["fNam"] = rec.fNam;
                row["fAdd"] = rec.fAdd;
                row["fCity"] = rec.fCity;
                row["fState"] = rec.fState;
                row["fCode"] = rec.fCode;
                row["oInfo"] = rec.oInfo;
                row["pgRecId"] = rec.pgRecId;
                row["lAct"] = rec.lAct;


                dataStore.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Write2LogFile("The data tables couldn't merge because: " + e.Message);
        }

        //Write from the Datatable source to the new spreadsheet and save it
        try
        {
            FileInfo newSheet = new FileInfo(fileName);
            using (ExcelPackage xPkg = new ExcelPackage(newSheet))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xPkg.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                var cell = worksheet.Cells;
                int rI = 2;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dataStore.Rows)
                {
                    string iDX = rI.ToString();

                    worksheet.Cells["A" + iDX].Value = dr["Prog"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["B" + iDX].Value = dr["cStatus"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["C" + iDX].Value = dr["bStatus"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["D" + iDX].Value = dr["fID"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["E" + iDX].Value = dr["fNam"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["F" + iDX].Value = dr["fAdd"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["G" + iDX].Value = dr["fCity"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["H" + iDX].Value = dr["fState"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["I" + iDX].Value = dr["fCode"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["J" + iDX].Value = dr["oInfo"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["K" + iDX].Value = dr["pgRecId"].ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells["L" + iDX].Value = dr["lAct"].ToString();

                    rI++;
                }

                xPkg.Save();
                MessageBox.Show("Data was successfully added to the current spreadsheet.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Write2LogFile("Data was not written to spreadsheet because: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.